# change css rule by input range

Tags: html, css

Can I change elem's css rule by input range without js?
Like this:

```
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100">
  <span>Some text</span>


 input[value="0"]+span {background:red;}
 input[value="50"]+span {background:green;}
```

Comment: Well the first thing I'd try is spelling `value` correctly. Beyond that this is what I'd try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the CSS parser would look for an attribute called `value` with a value of `0`. It's a stupid language and isn't meant to interpret the way you're hoping. You could add JS to give the input an actual `value` attribute with the appropriate value on range change, and then the CSS would pick up on it.

Example jQuery snippet:

```
$('[type="range"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).attr('value', this.value);
}).change();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/FqZZz/